# Is it possible to time-out session in Admin login of Prestoshop, if there is inactivity of admin

Tags: php, session, cookies, prestashop

I wanted to know if it possible to time-out session in Admin login of Prestoshop, if there is inactivity  of admin. If the admin is inactive for a specific time, it logout automatically. I tried by modifying the cookie.php file and setting a time but then the cookie expires after the time limit (irrespective of whether the user is away or working) and logs out the admin.

I want to logout the admin automatically if only he is inactive/idle/away for sometime.

Answer (score 0):

Set the time of the cookie on each page load to, say 10 minutes, then it will 
log out after 10 minutes without a page load.

Comment: There is a problem in this case. If i set the cookie timeout to 10 mins, then the cookie gets expired after 10 mins, irrespective of whether the admin is using it currently or idle/away. I want it to log out only if the admin is away.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution if you use prestashop 1.5 : http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/prestashop-15/basic-security/set-active-cookie-time

Comment: There is a problem in this case. If i set the cookie timeout to 10 mins, then the cookie gets expired after 10 mins, irrespective of whether the admin is using it currently or idle/away. I want it to log out only if the admin is away